# Would like create a relationship between 2 simple products (parent/child) when add to cart?

Tags: magento2, quote

I would like create a simple product (warranty) optional for customer choose when Add to cart, for example TV (parent product) can purchase 2 extra years warranty (child product). And I use quote_item.parent_item_id for related two simple product.

Function (implement)
1. Customer can see TV and Warranty product on cart/checkout flow.
2. When Customer delete the TV then the related warranty will be deleted, if more than one TV/Notedbook product on cart.

The problem....
1. I can use plugin to facilitate the relationship by add parent product ID on quote_item.parent_item_id, and facilitate deleted (child product) but the warranty product can't show on cart because the system look warranty product as configurable product.

Any suggestion? I need create new field on quote_item table and enhance delete item (parent/child) function? if yes, where to cart delete function code to follow up?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a common case for bundle product. 
Also if stock is not required for warranty, you can use customized options